# Angular 6 global request provider best practice

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

What is the best way of implementing an global request provider/service that could be injected into other providers ? Do you have an example that could take care of get/post/update/patch calls?

What I am trying to achieve, is instead of having:

```
getPferences() {
    return this.http.get(URL);
}
```

I would like something like:

```
this.apiRequest.load(URL, PARAMS).subscribe(...
```

I am trying to solve this because I need to append headers to every api call, and trying to keep this localized.

Thanks!

Comment: This is very broad without a single correct answer. Try implementing your own service and if you have problems come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Sounds like you're just trying to wrap the `httpClient` class?

Comment: *I need to append headers to every api call*: that's what interceptors are for. The documentation happens to have an example doing precisely that. Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: It may seem like boilerplate but I will advise you write the request calls for each module as required, unless they are singletons. Very handy when debugging.